# How can I deploy my react app with express back end deploy on Cpanel

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, cpanel, create-react-app

I have create react app for front and attach with node and express as back end attaches with firebase as the database I want to deploy on cPanel.
I set `npm run build` and past folder on public_html folder on cPanel
I also use putty and install node modules and nodejs on cPanel.
I paste my server file containing back end code and past with same node module folder now when I create `.htaccesss` and paste following code

PassengerBaseURI        /

PassengerAppRoot        /(path of my server)

PassengerAppType        node

PassengerStartupFile    server( file  name)

I get an error of and app stop

If I remove this file front end works perfectly fine back end does not work what should I need to do

Answer (score 0):

Set backend Nodejs/express as subdomain || still working on hoe to set the frontend React